# Correct use of abbreviation

Tags: writing

I am writing a scientific paper and I introduced the abbreviaton:
Underfloor heating system (UFH).

Can I now use UFH to talk about the underfloor heating system or do I have to write: UFH system?

I am asking because I have many pictures that are difficult to change were I use UFH (and it should stand for underfloor heating system).

Comment: Try asking on the English stack...

Comment: This may depend more on the opinion of the editors for the journal. Many journals in many fields would be fine with you using an abbreviation after you have defined it.

Comment: Does the sentence really need the word "system"? 'Heating' can act as a noun too.

Answer (score 0):

Your abbreviation is a bit misleading because you left out the initial of *system*, but you want it to mean system.

If you want to write just the abbreviation, I suggest you to use UFHS instead, to comprise *system*.